# Unicode range substitution not working

Tags: unicode-math

I'm using unicode-math to typeset and my main fonts are ArnoPro and GilSans for text, STIX Two for math and I have created a special one for caligraphic. I called it Math Caligraphic Alphabet.

So I substituted STIX Two cal glyphs for mine:

```
\setmathfont{Math Caligraphic Alphabet}[Scale=MatchLowercase,range={scr,bfscr}]
```

This worked perfect.

However, afterwards I decided to change BlackBoard glyphs in STIX (mainly, because they are sans serif ones) and I added to my font serif blackboard glyphs in their Unicode locations as I have previously done with cal glyphs, and I added:

```
\setmathfont{Math Caligraphic Alphabet}[Scale=MatchLowercase,range={scr,bfscr,bb}]
```

Example:

```
$\mathscr{A}\mathscr{B}\mathscr{C}$ % my cal letters

$\mathbb{A}\mathbb{B}\mathbb{C}$   % STIX Two bb letters
```

[image]

So, I changed the code adding a new line just to see if the font was working ok with my bb glyphs

```
\setmathfont{Math Caligraphic Alphabet}[range="211D]
```

and perfect

[image]

Then, I try two bb glyphs:

```
\setmathfont[range="211D,"2124]{Math Caligraphic Alphabet}
```

and `unicode-math` gave me the following error message:

```
! The key 'fontspec-opentype/"2124' is unknown and is being ignored.
! 
! See the LaTeX3 documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

l.108 ...e="211D,"2124]{Math Caligraphic Alphabet}
```

That's it. I cannot have all of my own bb glyphs working, even though I can have one of them working correctly.

Comment: Show a complete example. And also tell which version of unicode-math/fontspec/luatex you use. There have been changes.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that you need to add braces as shown, since unicode-math interprets a lone comma as separating successive keys:

```
\setmathfont[range={"211D,"2124}]{Math Caligraphic Alphabet}
```