# Font size of small caps

Tags: fontsize, typography

Small caps `\textsc{}` seem to use:

- *uppercase letters from the font* with the *default* font size for *typed uppercase* letters,
- *uppercase letters from the font* with a *smaller* font size for *typed lowercase* letters.

How can I adjust the latter font size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\textsc` does not select two fonts it just selects one, however it is a font in which lowercase letters use the shapes usually assigned to uppercase. The relative heights as always for the relative heights of upper and lower case vary from font to font but are the choice of the font designer not something to set from TeX.

Note that in most "true" caps-and-smalcaps fonts the small caps are not simply scaled down caps but designed to have a smaller overall size but similar stroke widths. "faked" small caps in which the lowercase is simply capitals from a smaller font often leave the uppercase looking excessively bold in comparison as it is not only larger but has correspondingly thicker stroke widths.

Comment: How would one go about overloading certain ranges and changing this? (And what is a range?)

Comment: @root actually I was thinking of unicode-math, see the examples of `range=` here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/420302/unicode-range-substitution-not-working  but that's probably not helpful if you want this for text use.

Comment: (Note to myself: `range=` is described in the documentation of the `unicode-math` package.)

Comment: Is it possible to influence the font size of the "lowercase" small caps, similarly to what probably happens when [initials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial) are used?

Comment: @root no as I say you would need to build a new font using a virtual font for pdftex or the lua on-the-fly interface to virtual fonts in luatex. It is like asking to change the shape of a g in a font, it's basically information that TeX doesn't have you need to address this at the font level.

Comment: What about the mechanisms that can give different font size to heading vs. text: Can they be modified to give different font size to first vs. other letters of a word?

Comment: @root  only if you want to mark up every word with a font change `{\large A}{BC}` but that is a very poor approximation to small caps (you can however of course do that without making any extra definitions at all)